# Trigonometry to radially spread points around a center

Tags: trigonometry, algorithms

I'm having a basic Math problem. I have number of point collections, each with a different amount of points. Let's say one collection has five points and I want them to spread radially around a center, with the distance of 20. So the spread angle for this collection is 360 / 5 = 72 ... now I'd need to calculate the x (adjacent?) and y (opposite?) based on the angle (72) and the hypothenuse (20)... so that in the end I have the x and y values for the points to place them radially around a center. Thanks for any help!

Here is my implementation in JavaScript so far: http://hastebin.com/ofajijuhok.coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spread angle is correct if you're trying to get an even spread around your central point.

Now we need to use some trigonometry. Remember all trigonometric functions work relative to the positive $x$-axis in a counter clockwise direction.

So for each of you points you need to calculate the following values for each of your $n$ points.

$$
\Delta x = h\cdot\cos(\theta)\\
\Delta y = h\cdot\sin(\theta)
$$
Where $\theta$ is the angle between the current point and the $x$ axis, most languages work in radians rather than degrees, and then offset by the center.

In pseudocode this looks like

```
    h = radius
    c = (x0,y0) //center point
    n = number_of_steps

    stepangle = 2*pi/n
    for i in 0..n-1
        theta = i * stepsize
        x = h * cos(theta) + c[0]
        y = h * sin(theta) + c[1] //these are your new x and y values
    end for
```

I can't see any major problems with your code, but I don't know too much about JQuery to tell if the loop is doing the right thing.